# JavascriptException in Selenium WebDriver

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, arcgis, esri

I tried to execute java script in selenium webdriver. The script is stored in a string variable. And variable is passed to exexuteScript() method. While running the script I got javascriptexception. The code, I executed is given below,

```
String js="<html>\r\n" + 
                "<head>\r\n" + 
                "    <link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"https://js.arcgis.com/3.18/dijit/themes/tundra/tundra.css\">\r\n" + 
                "    <link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"https://js.arcgis.com/3.18/esri/css/esri.css\"> \r\n" + 
                "   <script src=\"https://js.arcgis.com/3.31/\"></script>\r\n" + 
                "   <script>\r\n" + 
                "   var map;\r\n" + 
                "   var width = 123.26;\r\n" + 
                "   var height = 126.5;\r\n" + 
                "   require([\"esri/map\",\"esri/geometry/Point\", \"esri/SpatialReference\",\"esri/geometry/Extent\",\"esri/geometry/screenUtils\"],function(Map,Point,SpatialReference,Extent,screenUtils){\r\n" + 
                "       map = new Map(\"mapDiv\",{\r\n" + 
                "           basemap: \"streets\",\r\n" + 
                "           center: [-95.249, 38.954],\r\n" + 
                "           zoom: 5,\r\n" + 
                "           slider: false\r\n" + 
                "       });\r\n" + 
                "       //alert(point);\r\n" + 
                "       \r\n" + 
                "       var mappoint=new Point(-118.15, 33.80, new SpatialReference({ wkid: 4326 }));\r\n" + 
                "       console.log(mappoint);\r\n" + 
                "       \r\n" + 
                "       var extent = new esri.geometry.Extent({\r\n" + 
                "           \"xmin\":-122.68,\"ymin\":45.53,\"xmax\":-122.45,\"ymax\":45.6,\r\n" + 
                "           \"spatialReference\":{\"wkid\":4326}\r\n" + 
                "       });\r\n" + 
                "       console.log(extent);\r\n" + 
                "       var sp = esri.geometry.toScreenPoint(extent,width,height,mappoint);\r\n" + 
                "       console.log(sp);\r\n" + 
                "   });\r\n" + 
                "   </script>\r\n" + 
                "   </head>\r\n" + 
                "  <body>\r\n" + 
                "    <div id=\"mapDiv\"></div>\r\n" + 
                "    </div>\r\n" + 
                "  </body>\r\n" + 
                "</html>\r\n" + 
                "\r\n" + 
                "";
         JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
        executor.executeScript(js);
```

The error message I got is given below,

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptException: javascript error: Unexpected token '<'
  (Session info: chrome=79.0.3945.130)
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:25:48'
System info: host: 'DESKTOP-6H32JSB', ip: '10.8.2.62', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_231'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: false, browserName: chrome, browserVersion: 79.0.3945.130, chrome: {chromedriverVersion: 78.0.3904.105 (60e2d8774a81..., userDataDir: C:\Users\user\AppData\Local...}, goog:chromeOptions: {debuggerAddress: localhost:54082}, javascriptEnabled: true, networkConnectionEnabled: false, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platform: XP, platformName: XP, proxy: Proxy(), setWindowRect: true, strictFileInteractability: false, timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000}, unhandledPromptBehavior: dismiss and notify}
Session ID: 7c8b20fbb56364eb89ed96357cca06c4
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.createException(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:187)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:122)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:49)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:158)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:83)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:552)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.executeScript(RemoteWebDriver.java:489)
    at esrimap.ClickOnanyLocation.main(ClickOnanyLocation.java:85)
```

Please support me to solve this issue.

Comment: you are getting this error because your js string is not a js script, but a string with html tags, if you replace your String js = "console.log('this is a js script')"; you will actually see it being executed and printed to console

Answer (score 0):

In order to create a new page with javascript as you want you need create the page first (the DOM) and pass your variable:

```
String page = "window.open('').document.write(" + js + ")";
```

And then :

```
executor.executeScript(page);
```

Comment: How can I convert js string as a js script. Can U help me? @constantintrepadus

Comment: what do you mean by converting js string to js script ?